# Using Selenium webdriver - Unable to click on png image

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on `png` image. No error shown.

I have `image` on page :

```
<a target="_blank" href="/apex/Ball">
<img class="" src="/resource/1432049630000/CB_assets/img/genie-salesforce-badge.png">
</a>
```

---

My selenium webdriver code is :

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath));
element.click();
```

---

I tried to click on links on same page & its working fine.But unable to click on `png` image.

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: share html code of that image div.

Comment: why you can't click on <a>? And also, check your xpath.

Comment: See: [Selenium: The Advanced User Interactions API](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)